# MongoDB cross database query

Tags: mongodb, cross-database

I know I've seen this solution somewhere, but I can't seem to find it now.  I'm trying to query one MongoDB database while connected to another.  This should be possible without explicitly connecting to the other database before running the query.  Does anyone know the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: What's the context here?  In the shell or using a particular driver?

Answer (score 48):

To run a command against another database on the same MongoDB server, in the `mongo` shell you can use:

```
db.getSiblingDB('dbname').collection.command()
```

eg:

```
db.getSiblingDB('test').foo.find()
```