# Is it possible to do a $lookup aggregation between two databases in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-aggregation

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
use user; 

db.user.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "organization.organization",
          localField: "organizationId",
          foreignField: "uuid",
          as: "user_org"
        }
   }
])
```

`user` and `organization` are in two different databases.

*If this is not possible, what are the alternatives?*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is it possible to do a $lookup aggregation between two databases in
>   Mongodb?

It is not possible to query using lookup in two different db's.
[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in mongodb supports Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database.

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

We can use `getSibling("dbname")` to query another db from one db

```
db.getSiblingDB('test').foo.find()
```

Reference - [MongoDB cross database query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278814/mongodb-cross-database-query)

Comment: Oh ok. But how would I use that sibling db in the aggregation? Is it even possible?

Comment: It is not possible to use sibling in aggregation.

Comment: This answer needs to be updated as this seems to be possible now. See @gnopor's answer

Comment: Thanks, How about if the Database lives in different server? Is it still possible, using URI or something?

Answer (score 11):

Yes just read the following mongodb doc:

In Atlas Data Lake, `$lookup` can be used to perform a join of collections from different databases.

https://docs.mongodb.com/datalake/reference/pipeline/lookup-stage

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workaround for those who don't use Atlas Data Lake.

Let's assume we have `collection1` in `db1` and `collection2` in `db2`.

From `db1`, first merge `collection2`

```
db.getSiblingDB("db2").collection2.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "key1": "optional some condition to limit the number of results" }
    },
    {
        $project: { k2: "$optional projection to limit object attributes" }
    },
    {
        $merge: { into: { db: "db1", coll: "tmpCollection2" } }

    }
])
```

Then use is to lookup with collection1

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "tmpCollection2",
            localField: "localField",
            foreignField: "k2",
            as: "tmpCollection2_docs"
        }
    },
    {
        //Simulate the inner join if needed
        $match: {
            "tmpCollection2_docs": {
                $ne: []
            }
        }
    },
    {
       // Transform the array if needed
        $addFields: {
            "tmpCollection2_docs": {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$tmpCollection2_docs", 0]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: How effective is this? That's will copy the entire db?

Comment: The $merge will only copy the documents that match the filters in $match.
Since my original answer in 2022, we restructured our db to put all our collection in 1 db. When it is possible, it make things much easier in this case.