# how to $lookup from another database in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

i've 2 collections, named `user-profile` from database `user-service` and `user-wishlist` from database `pcrf-service`.

is it possible to do $lookup function in mongodb from another database?

i've used this: `db.getSiblingDB('dbname').collection.command()`

but it's not working.

here's my code:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("user-service");
db.getCollection("user-profile").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$sort" : { 
                "createdOn" : -1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "pcrf-service.user-wishlist", 
                "localField" : "mobile", 
                "foreignField" : "userId", 
                "as" : "contents"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to do a $lookup aggregation between two databases in Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222798/is-it-possible-to-do-a-lookup-aggregation-between-two-databases-in-mongodb)

Comment: nope, i''ve tried

Comment: i don't know what have you tried, but the answer in that question says its not possible to lookup in another database's collection.

Comment: From the documentation: "$lookup
New in version 3.2.
Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database"