# Spring Mongo how to do query across different datatbase

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I need to migrate from single database to two database,

and my project  have a lookup aggregation like

```
 LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("race")
            .localField("carId")
            .foreignField("carId")
            .as("result");


List<AggResult> outputs= racemongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "user",
                AggResult.class).getMappedResults();
```

across two collection"Race" and "User" in same database
now since two collection is separated, how can i do such a query in two different database,
say "Race" in database 1 , and "User" in database2

thanks

Comment: Can't be done with `$lookup`, you would need to use `$merge` which works across databases, to create a temporary collection for `race` in the same DB as the `user`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802209/1431750). If you are on Mongo Atlas [lookups across databases](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/supported-unsupported/pipeline/lookup-stage/) are supported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to do a $lookup aggregation between two databases in Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222798/is-it-possible-to-do-a-lookup-aggregation-between-two-databases-in-mongodb)

Comment: @aneroid  , how can merge be done in spring mongodb ?

Comment: Click on the linked answer in my comment above. It's just a pipeline ending with a `merge` step. So write it like you would in spring for any aggregation pipeline. A simple google search would bring you to the [spring docs & examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/mongodb/aggregation-framework.html).