# One Query to Join Multiple Mongo Databases for Dashboard

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have several separate Mongodb databases with identical collection structure.  They have to be separate databases for legal reasons.

I would like to be able to create a query that pulls data across all separate databases, combine the data into a single dataset so I get one view across all of my separate databased.

Assume that my databases are named db1, db2, db3.  Assume that the collections inside each are the same structure.  col1.name, col1.address, col1.zip

What kind of query will pull names from each collection from all databases?

Comment: Assuming you are on MongoDB Atlas you could use Federated Query in Atlas DataLake...

Comment: Does [MongoDB cross database query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278814/mongodb-cross-database-query) answer your question?